# How I can acces the mysql server running in docker container from remote host (PC2)?

Tags: docker

I am building a bidding system using Node, Mysql server,
Mysql server is running on PC1 by the following command:

docker container run --name bidding_mysql -v %cd%\bidding:/var/lib/mysql -p 3307:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=<password> -it mysql

,Then I'm login to another host(PC2) as Node application server< but when Iam tring to connect decorized mysql server,but I got the following error

Unable to connect to the database: ConnectionError [SequelizeConnectionError]: connect ETIMEDOUT??

"development": {
"username": "myusername",
"password": "mypassword",
"database": "bidding",
"host": "172.17.0.2", //IP of container running mysql server
"port":"3306",
"dialect": "mysql"
},
?????

How I can connect container remotely(from another PC) ?

How I can connect MYSQL server container running on host1 remotely( that is from host2 running Node app) ?

Comment: You need to use the _host's_ IP address, and the published port 3307.  Assuming the `172.17.0.2` address came from `docker inspect`, that's a Docker-internal IP address that's unreachable from outside the current host; you never need to look it up.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figure out it :)

1. Running a MySQL Docker Container(follow instructions in this article [https://phoenixnap.com/kb/mysql-docker-container](https://%20https://phoenixnap.com/kb/mysql-docker-container))

   -- create AppData directory and run cd to it

   -- docker container run --name <container_name> -v %cd%\bidding:/var/lib/mysql -p 3308:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=your_mysql_user_password -it mysql

2 . Configure host that running mysql container to forward all traffic come to 3308 to wsl2 (the virtual that running docker)

```
-- creat a proxy using:

netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=8090 listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=3308 connectaddress=$(wsl hostname -I)

-- allowing the port using:

netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=”Open Port 8090 for WSL2” dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=8090

-- Test proxy forwarding using:

Test-NetConnection -ComputerName localhost -Port 8090
```

3. In the config file of Database populate development object:

"development":{
"username": "mysql_user",
"password": "mysql_user_password",
"database": "db_name",
"host": "IP address of the Host that running mysql container",
"port":"8090",
"dialect": "mysql"
}